# Do we still need @Transactional in modern Spring Boot / SpringMVC applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, transactions

I haven't been up-to-date on Spring, and was talking to a coworker, and she said

> *Spring managed transactions take the default if there is no transactional annotation*

implying that we no longer need to do

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, 
               rollbackFor = Exception.class, 
               readOnly = false)
public void updateObject(Principal principal, String json) throws Exception {
   //...
 }
```

in modern Spring Boot or SpringMVC. Do we still need this `@Transactional` with `rollbackFor` ?

Comment: "Yes" you have to add @Transactional in spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [***Spring Framework Documentation*** [version 5.1.9.RELEASE]](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/index.html) (current stable):

> The @Transactional annotation is metadata that specifies that an
>   interface, class, or method must have transactional semantics (for
>   example, “start a brand new read-only transaction when this method is
>   invoked, suspending any existing transaction”)

So, yes you still need to use [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).

#### Further Reading:

- [Using `@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)
- [Understanding the Spring Framework’s Declarative Transaction Implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained)